# Google Earth: add markers in kml to show in street view

Tags: google-maps-markers, kml, google-earth, google-street-view

Is it possible to show the marker in street view? (smth like shown here, but it is in web  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays) The KML file is created in FME program and imported into google earth(current version 7.1.2.2041). The marker are shown in google maps but not in street view. Actually, it doesn't matter whether marker or pin or smth else. It is only important to recognize the desired position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexito, I have the same version of Google Earth as you, but I don't think Google Earth is the problem. I think the problem lies in the database imagery that is queried when you use Google Earth or Google Maps using a web browser. I have Firefox v31.2 & experience the same problem & noticed that this problem also started when Google Maps changed its UI to be more tablet friendly. This change must have occurred fairly recently.

Google Maps in Internet Explorer 8 DOES show the marker on street view & uses the good old UI that we've all grown to love & depend on. I wonder if you use IE9 or higher the Google Maps UI will change to the new version & you'll lose the marker on street view. Just another reason why I refuse to upgrade IE.

EXAMPLE OF WHY THE MARKER IS SO IMPORTANT: I was invited to a housewarming party & I was given the address. When I zoomed to street view, no marker. I found that the image wasn't even focused on the right house so I had to rotate the view until I found the house...by reading the address that was affixed to the wall of the house! And NO MARKER!